# Android studio Where to install NDK file? (downloaded it in zip)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, updates, subdirectory

My android studio said it wanted to update. But when I did I tried to update it but it wouldn't work so I had to launch: 
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat`
 to install other packages. But the NDK file wouldn't update, so I manually downloaded it from:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download

Now I have this `zip` file and where should I extract the folder?  Grateful for any help!!

The folder name is `android-ndk-r13b`.

Comment: Typically it goes in as a folder named `ndk-bundle` in the `Android\sdk` folder.  You can manually specify where the ndk is in Android Studio as well.

Comment: To be clear, `android-ndk-r13b` would be renamed `ndk-bundle`

Comment: In Android Studio, File menu | Project Structure... SDK Location

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, **rename** the extracted folder **`android-ndk-r13b`**(probably the exact name will be outdated someday soon) to **`ndk-bundle`** (you can put the `NDK` [and `SDK` for that matter] *anywhere*, and leave the name alone if you want {do not do this, I'm sure seen one case of hard-coded sub-path}),
 then, make the **settings point** to the location *where you put it*.

`Android Studio`, `File menu | Project Structure` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
(short-cut: ctrl+Alt+Shift+s):

[image: Android Studio, File menu | Project Structure]

It might also be helpful to you to *set/check* the following `environmental variables`:

```
NDK_HOME=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
NDK_MODULE_PATH=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
```

## EXTRA stuff:

While were doing `environmental variables` (belt-and-braces for `SDK`):

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
```

For JDK:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
JAVA_PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin
```

[JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) is the Java Development Kit.
[JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is the Java Run-time Environment.

If your *tight* on memory (`RAM`) for `Gradle` (700 Megabytes is about as low as you can go, other tools like `monitor.bat` use this variable too, it's *ubiquitous*) (clearly you *want* to make it as big a possible, without swapping making it *extremely* slow to build {note the underscore VERY important ! [it's a reserved name space conflict operator, don't ask me to explain it's VERY complicated !]}):

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx700m
```

## Some Links

[Setting up for Android NDK development](https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/11/11/setting-up-for-android-ndk-development/)
[Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)
[Getting Started with the NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html)
[Using C and C++ Code in an Android App with the NDK](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: For me these 3 dots were no clickable. I solved this by manually adding "ndk.dir=C:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle"  to local.properties file.

Answer (score 16):

Download the `.zip` file. Start the installation through `SDK manager`.
 Go to ***%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle*** and copy ***.installer*** folder to desktop and cancel the downloading in `SDK manager`. 
Open `.installer` folder and open ***.installationdata*** file and check the folder in which the file is being downloaded like:
 ***%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01***.
 Copy downloaded `.zip` file to the folder ***PackageOperation01*** or whatever listed in ***.installationdata*** file.
 Now copy the ***.installer*** folder from desktop to ***%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle***
 and start the `SDK manager`
 and start the installation again for `NDK`.
 The `SDK manager` will start the installation skipping the download process.

Comment: This also works on Linux when your `/tmp` just can't fit the entire NDK. Just download the NDK and symlink the zip to `/tmp/PackageOperation01/[zipname]` and symlink a folder on your larger disk to `/tmp/PackageOperation01/unzip`.

Comment: It just create another folder (e.g. PackageOperation02) whenever I cancel download in SDK manager

Comment: you are a genius :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to help those who are using MAC OSx, The process on MAC is as follows:

- download ndk-bundle in zip format
- run terminal
- use below command to find your temp directory in mac (e.g. /var/folders/sp/31g4p3kd5l10c68qdy475krr0000gn/T/)

  echo $TMPDIR
- change directory to PackageOperation01

  cd PackageOperation01
- copy ndk-bundle.zip into the directory

  cp /path/to/ndk-bundle.zip /$TMPDIR/PackageOperation01/
- start Android Studio and in SDK-Manager try to install ndk-bundle again.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, With Android studio 3.3.2, SDK Manager keeps choosing new temporary folder to download the ndk-bundle. The following steps helped to install the downloaded ndk zip file.

1. Go to SDK manager, start downloading NDK.
2. Go to `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/.installer`
3. cat .installData

`path=/var/folders/vr/mz4hsqqs0wlgj9sfcpn3wfn5g2lwk3/T/PackageOperation07`

PackageOperation0X is the temp folder chosen to download the zip file

4. Copy downloaded [android-ndk-r21d-darwin-x86_64.zip](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) to this temp folder (PackageOperation0X)
5. Copy `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` folder to some other location
6. Cancel the NDK download in SDK Manager
7. `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/`
8. You may find ndk-bundle folder missing as download has been cancelled in the SDK Manager.
9. Move the previously copied ndk-bundle to `~/Library/Android/sdk/`
10. Go to SDK manager, start downloading NDK again. Existing file will be scanned and installation will be started skipping the download step.