# Android Studio NDK different user name - Gradle Build Error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I got an android studio project from another person and I am having issues building/debugging due to (I believe) the NDK path.

The error I am getting is "Execution faild for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug' due to starting command 'C\Users\**OtherUserName**\...\ndk-build.cmd'

I have changed the NDK location in File->Project Structure so it is correct but I am not sure what else I need to do. When I do a ctrl-shift-f and find all **OtherUserName** there is over 1000 occurrences. Any advice on what I need to do?

I am able to Build->Make Project, but when I run->Debug I get a gradle build error described above.

Comment: I would suggest your "another person" has hard-coded a path in their code (C\Users\OtherUserName\...\ndk-build.cmd) OUTSIDE of what they have given you (using absolute paths). So you probably don't have ALL the code you need. I would suggest you ask them to fix their code (using relative paths) or share the missing code. ALSO see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474050/android-studio-where-to-install-ndk-file-downloaded-it-in-zip/40475804#40475804 for simple environment setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have no choice but get rid of all occurrences of **OtherUserName** (but maybe some are pure coincidences).

To begin with, clean up your project: delete the directories **build**, **.externalNativeBuild** (recursive for the project). Delete all **local.properties** and **.iml** files. I hope that there won't be too many problematic occurrences left. Fix them in your favorite text editor, and import the resulting gradle project into your Android Studio.

**NB** During all these manipulations, keep a full copy of the original project available as a backup, if some important file gets deleted or screwed up by mistake.