# How to prevent from C++ to recompile all files in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using the Android Studio with NDK and [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) in a project with a large amount of C++ files. When I make changes in a single C++ file
**it won't apply in the code unless I rebuild the whole project** and refresh the entire C++ files so they have to recompile.

The compilation process takes more than 3 minutes for every small change. Make it 20 times a day and you have lost an hour.

According to today, after I make a change to a file I go to menu *Build* → *Refresh Linked C++ Projects* and then run the project, resulting in a full, redundant compilation of all files.

I'm looking for way for the compiler to refresh only the changed file, and as a result shorten the build process.

***Note:*** This problem only occurs in Windows. When I run Android Studio on a Mac, the compiler recompiles only the relevant files.

This is my [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

FILE(GLOB CPP_SRC
     "src/main/cpp/*.c"
     "src/main/cpp/*.h"
     "src/main/cpp/*.cpp"
     "src/main/cpp/*.hpp"
)

add_library(MyLib
             SHARED
             ${CPP_SRC})

find_library(log-lib
              log)

target_link_libraries(MyLib
                       ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries(MyLib
                      android
                      log
                      EGL
                      GLESv2)
```

And my *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '*****'
            storeFile file(*****)
            storePassword '*****'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release", "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions"
                cppFlags "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS", '-Ofast', '-fsigned-char', "-std=c++14", "-frtti", "-fexceptions", "-mtune=arm7", "-mfpu=vfpv3-d16", "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "-Wall",
                        "-DCOMPILE_EUROPE_ID_AND_FACE_OCR_MANAGER",
                        "-DCOMPILE_FRENCH_PASSPORT_SIGNATURE",
                        "-DCOMPILE_FRENCH_ID_BACK_OCR",
                        "-DCOMPILE_FRENCH_PASSPORT_SIGNATURE_MANAGER",
                        "-DCOMPILE_PASSPORT_AND_FACE_OCR_MANAGER",
                        "-DCOMPILE_MRZ_OCR",
                        "-DCOMPILE_FRENCH_ID_BACK_OCR_MANAGER"
            }

            ndk {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }

        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    libraryVariants.all { variant -> variant.outputs.all { output ->
                          outputFileName = "${"libScanovateImaging"}.aar" }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Might be a problem with your project's [Application.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk) or [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk) files. Don't know enough about Android Studio to know for sure.

Comment: If this misbehavior on Windows only happens in Android Studio, but command-line **ndk-build** or **cmake** do partial recompile correctly, you can run the native build in the Terminal window (make sure that you use exactly same paths and parameters as AS does).

Comment: Do you have `minifyEnabled true` property in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Could this be because of `GLOB` ? I mean, if you list the source files explicitly, this may be resolved. And I don't think you need `.h` and `.hpp` files in `${CPP_SRC}`

Comment: You have a typo in your `build.gradle` file (`libraryVariants.all` has one too many curly end brace). I have tested two `ABIs` and `ndkBuild` does it correctly (see updated answer -> Structure). `splits` is ok. It must be your `CMakeLists.txt`, as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285443/androidstudio-rebuilds-everything-every-time-if-multiple-abis-are-supported) suggests. Show your Structure as I have (it will be in a different place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the cause to the problem.

In my project I have worked with *[symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)* C++ files.
The NDK cannot immediately apply the changes made in these files and they 
won't be expressed in your app unless you rebuild the whole project.

**The solution is to work with hard copy files.**

If I find some way to work correctly with symlink files it would be better
for my needs. Until then I can at least edit single or multiple files without recompiling the whole project.

This is a relatively esoteric situation but might be helpful for
someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

I think this has been a problem for a **long time** (judging by the complaints) in Android Studio (more specifically the `NDK` build system). Now, in the latest version, it is finally ready and working (hopefully).

Note: [`gradlew`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) builds are significantly faster than using the `Android Studio IDE`, and can be built using a batch file script ([`.bat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)).

## CMake possible problems(P = problem, C = cause, S = solution)

(P1) `Android Studio` rebuilds everything every time if multiple ABIs are supported See [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285443/androidstudio-rebuilds-everything-every-time-if-multiple-abis-are-supported).
(C1) Build variants all had the same output directory for the .o files.
(S1) You need to split out the build directory into release/debug and into the different ABIs.

## My Setup (ndkBuild)

`Android Studio 3.1`, `NDK release 10`, `gradle` version 4.4 (plugin 3.1.0)

I have 2 libraies to build (`libhello_world.so` with 1 c++ file, and `libjni_photoeditor.so` with 24 c++ files).

I am using `externalNativeBuild` -> `ndkBuild` to [build](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) my native code (you *could* use [`CMake`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake) also, I have not tested that).

**app level `build.gradle`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                minSdkVersion 16
                targetSdkVersion 16
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                ndk {
                }//ndk
            }//defaultConfig

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android-optimize.txt'))
                    proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
                }//release
                debug {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    jniDebuggable true
                    renderscriptDebuggable true
                }//debug
            }//buildTypes
            
            externalNativeBuild {
                // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
//              cmake {
//                // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
//                path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
//              }
                ndkBuild {
                //****this is the working build****
                    path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'
                }//ndkBuild
            }//externalNativeBuild
        }//android
        
        dependencies {
        }//dependencies
```

**`Application.mk`:**

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

**`Android.mk`:**

```
#================================================
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) #only call it ONCE !
#================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE      := hello_world
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  hello_world.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE      := libjni_photoeditor
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libm liblog libjnigraphics
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics -lbcc
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := _jni.cpp utils.cpp quantize.cpp #etc.. 24 files
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror \
    -I$(OUT)/../../../../frameworks/compile/libbcc/include
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -L$(OUT)/system/lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

## Test 1. Android Studio `Build -> Build APK(s)` build

**(A)** **Modify** one of my projects 24 `C++` files (`quantize.cpp`) and rebuild.

**(B)** `Build -> Build APK(s)`

**(C)** Only the C:\Android\PhotoRend1\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs-debug\jni_photoeditor\quantize.o timestamp changed (and the library).

## Test 2. `gradlew` terminal window (command line) build

From the project root I use [`gradlew`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) in a `terminal window` to `assemble` my `apk`.

**(1)** Every thing is up-to-date build:

> C:\Android\PhotoRend1>gradlew assembleDebug

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Configure project :app
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build hello_world armeabi-v7a
make.exe: `C:/Android/PhotoRend1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello_world.so' is up to date.
Build jni_photoeditor armeabi-v7a
make.exe: `C:/Android/PhotoRend1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libjni_photoeditor.so' is up to date.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 46s
```

**(2)** **Modify** one of my projects 24 `C++` files (quantize.cpp) and re-assemble.

**(3)** One file changes is up-to-date build:

> C:\Android\PhotoRend1>gradlew assembleDebug

```
> Configure project :app
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build hello_world armeabi-v7a
make.exe: `C:/Android/PhotoRend1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello_world.so' is up to date.
Build jni_photoeditor armeabi-v7a
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: jni_photoeditor <= quantize.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libjni_photoeditor.so
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 59s
```

**(4)** As you can see it did an incremental build.

Some links:
[Manual `NDK` updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474050/android-studio-where-to-install-ndk-file-downloaded-it-in-zip/40475804#40475804)

Comment: I have updated my gradle to 4.4. I am using android 3.1.2 and NDK 16. I am obliged to use CMake build for native code. I have built the project from the cmd with gradlew assemblerelease but the problem continues. Can your solution be tested with CMake?

Comment: I have added my CMake and gradle files. I will also try to look into your latest answer