# After using android studio 3.1.2 it showing error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-ndk

After installing `Ubuntu 18` in new desktop with i7 and 24gb ram . We try to move our `android studio` project to new pc in zip format and our project work fine on old pc but it showing error on new pc .

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for
>   task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command
>   '/home/developer/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip''
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:220)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:204)
>         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:340)
>     at
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:39)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException:
>   Could not start
>   '/home/developer/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip'
>     at
>   net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
>     at
>   net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/home/developer/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip"
>   (in directory
>   "/home/developer/Documents/working_app/valyangadi_firebase_project/app"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 10 more

What is this errors and How to solve this problem?
This project works fine on my old laptop `Ubuntu 14.04` LTS that using android studio 3.0

Comment: Apparently `/home/developer/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/mips64el-linux-android-strip` does not exist on your new computer. Do you really need to build for mips64?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but with `..\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip`. I think it's related to Android Studio update I've installed yesterday, but everything was working fine. Today when I try to compile, this error pops out.

Comment: Where can i download old version android studio ?

Comment: Umm, google it? Unfortunately I thought of that and downgraded AS to version 3.0.1, but nothing has changed. I still get the same error, so bug must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 20):

You should check Android Studio configuration on you old PC and compare version of every position in **Android SDK > SDK Tools**:

[image]

In my case the main problem was with Android NDK. Apparently I've installed update to version 17 and that was causing problems. So what I did:

1. Remove everything from directory `[android-sdk]\ndk-bundle\` **or** uninstall Android NDK in **Android Studio\Sdk tools** (see on the image above)
2. Close Android Studio (AS).
3. Download (in my case) NDK version 16b from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases
4. Extract archive (10 directories and 8 files or so) to `[android-sdk]\ndk-bundle\`
5. Start AS and perform full refresh: **Build > Refresh Linked C++ projects** and **Build > Rebuild project**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would I go about refreshing and rebuilding if I was building the app using the ionic framework built on cordova, since it uses the Android SDK and NDK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cordova, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475804/5273427) you could check if you have `ndk-bundle` directory inside `Android SDK directory`. If so, remove it, download another package (older if you need) extract it somewhere and rename to **ndk-bundle**. Then paste it to where you deleted previous ndk directory and rebuild.

Comment: Yeah so I did that and the exception is no longer being thrown but now I am getting the wierdest exception thrown of all time in which it the exception that fails the build is "Already Finished" Here is my error log:                                              
                    "BUILD FAILED in 3s
(node:31772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Already finished"   Does not make much sense to me.

Comment: I'd try restarting PC and building project again. If it won't help, start new question, comments are not meant for problems solving.

Comment: Can't really start a question when I don't have the ability to do so. Trying to earn enough reputation back to get that privilege back. It has been a long time since I have had the ability to ask questions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Restarting my computer and rebuilding the project worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

include this code in your build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip '*/mips/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/mips64/*.so'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mips is not supported anymore in Android NDK r17. I had the same problem and in my case it was caused by a dependency which contains a prebuilt mips native lib. I was able to fix the build error by excluding the mips files as follows in the main build.gradle:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/mips64/NAME_OF_THE_LIB.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/NAME_OF_THE_LIB.so'
    }
}
```

where NAME_OF_THE_LIB must be replaced by the actual name of the so file. You can find it by unzipping the apk of a previous successful build, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below simple steps to fix this:

1. Close All opened file.
2. Close Android Studio.
3. After that, restart your mac, and rebuild your project from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches and Restart fixed it for me.
go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Hope it works for you.