# null arguments NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm new to use **NDK** I've installed it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474050/android-studio-where-to-install-ndk-file-downloaded-it-in-zip)

After that, I get some errors of null variables with messages

> Error while executing process E:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd
> with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=F:\XX\XXX\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
>
> NDK_APPLICATION_MK=F:\XX\XXX\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk
>
> APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1
>
> APP_PLATFORM=android-21
>
> NDK_OUT=F:/XX/XXX/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>
> NDK_LIBS_OUT=F:\XX\XXX\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib
> F:/XX/XXX/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libemu.so}

it took me about three days searching
can anyone help me in that?

Edit: after taking another round in StackOverflow I get these errors now.

> [armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : emu <= ticks.c [armeabi-v7a] Compile++
>
> thumb: emu <= main.cpp [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: emu <=
>
> emumedia.cpp [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: emu <= emulator.cpp
>
> [armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : nativehelper <= JNIHelp.c [armeabi-v7a]
>
> SharedLibrary  : libnativehelper.so

Comment: The best way to sort it out would be to run `ndk-build` from command line with exactly same parameters, maybe adding `V=1` argument.

Comment: what do you mean? I just try to run the app and get that error

Comment: the error message you posted looks like generated by Android Studio. I suggest that you try to reproduce it from command line.

Comment: yes, it comes from android studio logs. how to try from command? you mean Terminal? if yes what should I write?

Comment: why not use CMake?

Comment: Yes, you can open the Terminal window in Android Studio, and type `E:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd V=1 NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=F:\XX\XXX\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk` *and so on* exactly as you see in the error message.

Comment: @shizhen I'm new to use ndk and these are files included in NESOID game project. can you suggestme how to do it?

Comment: @AlexCohn I get this error message `Android NDK: NDK_PROJECT_PATH==null.  Please explicitly set NDK_OUT to directory for all generated intermediate files.
E:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\build\\..\build\core\build-local.mk:177: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
`

Comment: check the edit please too

Comment: These `[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb …` are not errors, that's normal build log. But you missed `APP_ABI=arm64-v8a`, so NDK was building the default 32-bit **armeabi-v7a** for you

Comment: so how to solve this error  get about 3 days in it

Comment: What's the problem? There are no errors in the second part of your question.

Comment: it refuse to build my app to run on my mob >> maybe as I'm trying to run neso app on android 6?